# react native firebase user registration issue

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, undefined

I am new to react-native and currently doing user authentication on react-native with the use of firebase.

As of right now, I am doing the user registration feature where the user registers and the credentials will be saved to firebase

However i am getting this error of

> undefined is not a function (evaluating 'this.setState({ error :
>   ", loading: true })')

I have no idea what went wrong and how to fix it and would need some help thank you!

My code for the user registration page is this

```
class RegisterScreen extends React.Component{

    _onPressSubmit(){
        console.log('register submit btn pressed')

        this.state({ error: '', loading: true});

        const { email, password } = this.state;

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then(() => { 
            this.state({error: '', loading: false});
            this.props.navigation.navigate('Main');
        })
        .catch(() => {
            this.state({error: 'Registration failed', loading: false});
        })
    }

    render() {      
        return (
            <ScrollView> 
                <View style = {[styles.container]}> 

                    <Text></Text>

                    <TextInput  style = {[styles.textSpace]}
                        //label = 'Email Address' 
                        placeholder = 'Email' 
                        keyboardType = 'email-address'
                        //TBA />

                    <TextInput 
                       // label = 'Password'
                        placeholder = 'Password'
                        //TBA />

                    <Text style={styles.textPadding}></Text> 

                    <Text style={styles.textPadding}></Text>

                    <Button 
                        onPress = {this._onPressSubmit}
                        title = 'Submit' />
                </View>
            </ScrollView>
        );
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the error says that state is not a function of Component.

maybe are you trying to set the State? If so, instead of:

```
this.state({ error: '', loading: true});
```

it should be:

```
this.setState({ error: '', loading: true});
```

theres's at least 3 occurrences in the code sample.

Comment: Heya! , Thanks a lot for checking my mistake and pointing it out. Your answer resolved my current issue. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `this.state()` use `this.setState({})`
When mutating